# Observe livedata inside a for loop

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I want to update a list in my activity that depends on the data of another list. Both the data list are being observed from the activity from the my viewmodel. After I get the data from my firstlist I need to run a for loop on this list to get the required ids and get the data for the second list.

But keeping the livedata observer in the for loop is causing a lot of problems. The for loop runs as expected but the livedata observer is getting called almost double the amount of the for loop. This happens only the first time when the list in being brought from the api. When I do the same operation a second time where the list is cached and is being brought from the database, the problem does not occur. Below is the source code for the problem,

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {

    final String uId = firstList.get(i).item.uid;
    final long id = firstList.get(i).item.id;
    viewModel.initAnotherItemRepository(uId, id);
    viewModel.getSecondItem().observe(this, new Observer<Resource<List<SecondItem>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Resource<List<SecondItem>> listResource) {
            if (listResource.data != null) {
                secondItemList.addAll(listResource.data);
                if (count == firstList.size() - 1) {
                    //Do something

                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (listResource.state == Resource.STATE_FAILURE) {
                showLoadingSpinner(false);
            }
        }
    }

    );
}
```

Comment: Need more detail on when getSecondItem() method livedata triggers. Does initAnotherItemRepository(uId, id) method call triggers the second list livedata?

Comment: Yes. the initAnotherItemRepository call triggers the second list live data.
```
public void initAnotherItemRepository(@Nullable String uId, long id) {
secondData = anotherListRepository.getSecondItems(uId, id);
}
```

Comment: Can you try placing observe logic outside the for loop and let me know if you face the issue? I believe placing the logic outside the for loop should resolve the problem

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul Now it seems the last item that was initialised in the loop only gets observed. But I need data for all the items that I am getting from the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try to observe SecondItem outside the for loop. It gets data whenever update

```
viewModel.getSecondItem().observe(this, new Observer<Resource<List<SecondItem>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Resource<List<SecondItem>> listResource) {
        if (listResource.data != null) {
            secondItemList.addAll(listResource.data);
            if (count == firstList.size() - 1) {
                //Do something

            }
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (listResource.state == Resource.STATE_FAILURE) {
            showLoadingSpinner(false);
        }
    }
}

);

for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {

    final String uId = firstList.get(i).item.uid;
    final long id = firstList.get(i).item.id;
    viewModel.initAnotherItemRepository(uId, id);
}
```

Comment: Now it seems the last item that was initialised in the loop only gets observed. But I need data for all the items that I am getting from the for loop.

Comment: That should not happen, Can you add your ViewModel implementation ?